# enhancing d3 code in assigning data from csv file to an array variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Could you please throw some lights as to how the below code can be enhanced in assigning data from csv file to an array variable.

below are the code snippets

http://jsbin.com/newetekegi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: this looks like the same question that I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36971701/d3js-updates-only-once try those two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct inbuilt api you need to parse the file and place it in array. Have a look at this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1525346).